# Split Workbook into multiple workbooks based on two columns

Tags: vba, excel, automation, excel-2010

I hope everyone is well.

I am look for some help. I am looking to automate a workbook which splits the data from the master file to the individual workbooks based on column H. What needs to be done first is that Column T needs to be filtered to 'Owned' or 'Impacted'. Column H then needs to be split into the separate workbooks. based on what may be in column H. On each new workbook created, whatever is under column H there needs to be two tabs, one tab for 'Owned' and one tab for 'Impacted'. This would need to be then saved as whatever the name of the cell was and the date.

The additional difficult bit is under column H, in each cell as per the attached there could be A, B, C, D, E, F as individual cells, but there could also be cells with multiple letters in them. If they have multiple letters each one needs to go into all the workbooks that are mentioned in the cell. So, for example if there is a cell with A, B, C, D, this would mean it would have to go into the workbook for the individual workbooks for A, B, C, and D.

I have attached the file image[image] and I have the below code which I used. It does work, however due to the above issue with the multiple criteria in the cells it is splitting the workbooks further into individual workbooks. Does anyone know if a drop down can be added where I can select the criteria from column H and T, or another work around please. I am happy to try another code if necessary. Example workbook attached as well.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ParseItems()
'Based on selected column, data is filtered to individual workbooks
'workbooks are named for the value plus today's date
Dim LR As Long, Itm As Long, MyCount As Long, vCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet, MyArr As Variant, vTitles As String, SvPath As String

'Sheet with data in it
Set ws = Sheets("Master")

'Path to save files into, remember the final \
 SvPath = "\\My Documents\New folder\"

'Range where titles are across top of data, as string, data MUST
'have titles in this row, edit to suit your titles locale
 vTitles = "A1:V1"

'Choose column to evaluate from, column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
 vCol = Application.InputBox("What column to split data by? " & vbLf _
    & vbLf & "(A=1, B=2, C=3, etc)", "Which column?", 8, Type:=1)
  If vCol = 0 Then Exit Sub

'Spot bottom row of data
LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vCol).End(xlUp).Row

'Speed up macro execution
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Get a temporary list of unique values from key column
ws.Columns(vCol).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, 
CopyToRange:=ws.Range("HH1"), Unique:=True

'Sort the temporary list
ws.Columns("HH:HH").Sort Key1:=ws.Range("HH2"), Order1:=xlAscending, 
Header:=xlYes, _
   OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, 
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

'Put list into an array for looping (values cannot be the result of 
formulas, must be constants)
MyArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("HH2:HH" & 
Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))

'clear temporary worksheet list
 ws.Range("HH:HH").Clear

'Turn on the autofilter, one column only is all that is needed
 ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter

'Loop through list one value at a time
For Itm = 1 To UBound(MyArr)
    ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter Field:=vCol, Criteria1:=MyArr(Itm)

    ws.Range("A1:A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    MyCount = MyCount + Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SvPath & MyArr(Itm) & Format(Date, " MM-DD-YY") & 
  ".xlsx", 51   'use for Excel 2007+
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter Field:=vCol
  Next Itm

'Cleanup
 ws.AutoFilterMode = False
 MsgBox "Rows with data: " & (LR - 1) & vbLf & "Rows copied to other sheets: 
" & MyCount & vbLf & "Hope they match!!"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "it is splitting the workbooks further into individual workbooks"? Could you elaborate? Is it creating a workbook named "A, B, C" instead of just going into workbook A, workbook B and workbook C?

Comment: Yes that is correct it is creating it into workbooks A,B, C instead of going into workbook A, workbook b etc.

Comment: You'll probably need utilize the `Split()` and delimit those values by `,` so that you can break it up.

Comment: Copy the whole thing to a new workbook then use [tag:autofilter] to show everything that shouldn't be there and delete it. Sometimes it is easier to get rid of what you don't want rather than copy what you do want.

Comment: I believe that `LBound(MyArr)` is zero, not one and you are looping through to 1,048,575.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than applying filters to the worksheet you could load the entire dataset into an array and then store the row index #s for each of the various criteria. You can then use the row index lists to slice the array for each respective output.

I don't have your source data (couldn't see the attached file) but would this approach work?

```
Sub VariableCollections()

Dim HeaderVals() As Variant
Dim SourceData() As Variant, Criteria As Variant
Dim RowIndexLists As New Collection, ColIndexList As String
Dim KeyStore As New Collection, Key As Variant
Dim i As Long, Temp As String
Dim fName As String, fFormat As Long
Dim OutputArr() As Variant

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Master") 'change if necessary

    'store table header values in array (A1:W1)
    HeaderVals = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(, 23).Value

    'store data in array, assume starts at A2
    SourceData = .Cells(2, 1).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 23).Value

End With

'index row #s for each Criteria & Owned/Impacted
For i = LBound(SourceData, 1) To UBound(SourceData, 1)

    If SourceData(i, 23) = "Owned" Then 'col W

        'loop each Criteria (col H) for current row
        For Each Criteria In Split(SourceData(i, 8), ", ")

            'test if key already added to KeyStore
            If Not InCollection(KeyStore, Criteria) Then KeyStore.Add Criteria, Criteria

            'test if Criteria already added to RowIndexLists
            If InCollection(RowIndexLists, Criteria & "_Own") Then 'already added...

                '...update row index value for current key
                Temp = RowIndexLists(Criteria & "_Own")
                RowIndexLists.Remove (Criteria & "_Own")
                RowIndexLists.Add Temp & "," & i, Criteria & "_Own"

            Else 'not already stored...

                '...Create New Item
                RowIndexLists.Add i, Criteria & "_Own"

            End If

        Next Criteria

    ElseIf SourceData(i, 23) = "Impacted" Then 'col W

        'loop each Criteria (col H) for current row
        For Each Criteria In Split(SourceData(i, 8), ", ")

            'test if key already added to KeyStore
            If Not InCollection(KeyStore, Criteria) Then KeyStore.Add Criteria, Criteria

            'test if Criteria already added to RowIndexLists
            If InCollection(RowIndexLists, Criteria & "_Imp") Then 'already added...

                '...update row index value for current key
                Temp = RowIndexLists(Criteria & "_Imp")
                RowIndexLists.Remove (Criteria & "_Imp")
                RowIndexLists.Add Temp & "," & i, Criteria & "_Imp"

            Else 'not already stored...

                '...Create New Item
                RowIndexLists.Add i, Criteria & "_Imp"

            End If

        Next Criteria

    End If

Next i

'save in same directory as current workbook
fName = Split(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".")(0)

'set file format # based on OS type
#If Mac Then
    fFormat = 52
#Else
    fFormat = 51
#End If

'assumes cols 8 (H) and 23 (W) are no longer needed in output
ColIndexList = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22"

'slice HeaderVals array for matching cols
HeaderVals = Application.Index(HeaderVals, 0, Split(ColIndexList, ","))

'write out to new workbooks
For Each Key In KeyStore

    'create new workbook
    With Workbooks.Add

        'output "Owned" matches for current Criteria (key value) if exist
        If InCollection(RowIndexLists, Key & "_Own") Then

            'slice array to indexed rows
            OutputArr = Application.Index(SourceData, _
                        Application.Transpose(Split(RowIndexLists(Key & "_Own"), ",")), _
                        Split(ColIndexList, ","))

            'add new worksheet, rename & output data
            With .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))

                'rename sheet
                .Name = "Owned"

                'test if OutputArr has 2 dimensions
                If IsArray2D(OutputArr) Then '2D i.e. rows & cols
                    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(, UBound(OutputArr, 2)) = HeaderVals
                    .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(OutputArr, 1), UBound(OutputArr, 2)) = OutputArr
                Else '1D i.e. single row
                    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(, UBound(OutputArr)) = HeaderVals
                    .Cells(2, 1).Resize(, UBound(OutputArr)) = OutputArr
                End If

            End With

        End If

        'output "Impacted" matches for current Criteria (key value) if exist
        If InCollection(RowIndexLists, Key & "_Imp") Then

            'slice array to indexed rows
            OutputArr = Application.Index(SourceData, _
                        Application.Transpose(Split(RowIndexLists(Key & "_Imp"), ",")), _
                        Split(ColIndexList, ","))

            'add new worksheet, rename & output data
            With .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))

                'rename sheet
                .Name = "Impacted"

                'test if OutputArr has 2 dimensions
                If IsArray2D(OutputArr) Then '2D i.e. rows & cols
                    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(, UBound(OutputArr, 2)) = HeaderVals
                    .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(OutputArr, 1), UBound(OutputArr, 2)) = OutputArr
                Else '1D i.e. single row
                    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(, UBound(OutputArr)) = HeaderVals
                    .Cells(2, 1).Resize(, UBound(OutputArr)) = OutputArr
                End If

            End With

        End If

        'delete sheet1
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Sheets(1).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        'save file & close
        .SaveAs fName & "_" & Key, fFormat
        .Close

    End With

Next Key

ErrorHandler: If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Error # " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

as @dwirony suggested it utilizes the `Split` function on col H to break apart the various criteria on each row and then stores the row # in a collection.

I realize a `Dictionary` would be a better suited here rather than using `Collections`, however as Dictionaries are Windows only I prefer to avoid them unless I know for certain the file will only ever be used on Windows. If this is the case then the above code could be simplified by switching the collections out for a dictionary.

@jeeped Excel creates base-1 arrays when directly assigning a `Range` object to an array. I've always assumed to make them similar to the `(ROW,COL)` addressing.

==== Edit 6/30 ====

Updated code to reflect changes to data layout:

- Additional cols in data range
- `Owned/Impacted` col moved to `Col W`
- Adjusted `Worksheet` reference to match OPs request

Comment: Hi thanks for this and apologies for the delay. Unfortunately when I try to implement the code it seems to come as a mismatch error and also a subscript error. I had to extend the data to column W. Column W has the Impacted and Owned data. Do you know why this isn't working for me? Also the sheet on the file where the code is running is call Master. Could you help please?

Comment: Are you able to post a copy or link to your file? I based the code on the reference image you posted. I suspect the issue might be because the impacted/owned column has moved from col T (as shown in your ref image) to col W.

Comment: I just updated the code to reflect the correct sheet name and the additional cols in your data - see if that works